# Faraday::ConnectionFailed at /auth/facebook/callback getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faraday, omniauth-facebook

My rails app was working fine before but now after I log in from facebook I get this error. I did a google search but nothing worked for me. After loggin in from my app, I get this error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by deleting the entry in database, after that try again to login via facebook